# BLE device is not listed under the Bluetooth device list in the Bluetooth settings

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-plx

I am trying to build a mobile application that read data from WaterRower machine via BLE. This is the machine I am talking about, https://www.waterrower.co.uk/waterrower-natural-rowing-machine. The WaterRower has its own app, https://apps.apple.com/us/app/waterrower-monitor/id1463763094 that can connect to the machine's bluetooth/ BLE and read data from it. But when I download the app and open the app, the app can find the WaterRower machine and connects to it via Bluetooth. The WaterRower app can find the machine's Bluetooth as follow within the app.

[image]

As you can see, the WaterRower machine bluetooth's name is PD1186. When the machine is connected, I can also see that in the device's Bluetooth list as follow.

[image]

When the machine is connected to my iPhone's Bluetooth within the WaterRower app, it also appeared in the connected Bluetooth devices list of the phone. But if I tried to find the WaterRower machine without using the WaterRower app, the machine's Bluetooth is not listed as you can see below. My iPhone cannot scan it.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the WaterRower machine is not listed under the scanned device list at all. It can only be found and connected using the WaterRower app. Also, I am trying to list down the devices in ReactNative following this article, https://blog.bam.tech/developer-news/make-your-first-iot-react-native-application-with-the-bluetooth-low-energy. But the WaterRower machine is not on the list at all.

What kind of BLE technology is that? Is that some sort of private tech to WaterRower? Can I not build my own app and pair it with the machine to read the data? Is it even possible to pair with the machine from my own app? Why is it not evening appearing under the iPhone Bluetooth device list and can only be connected from the app?

Comment: It is BLE. BLE devices often aren't bonded so they won't appear in the Bluetooth list when they aren't connected. Use an app from the App Store like LightBlue to connect and examine its services and characteristics. There are standard profiles for exercise machines and I would be very surprised if this device doesn't implement those.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a go. Cheers.

Comment: If a device only offers BLE, not a dual mode of BLE and Bluetooth classic, they never appear in the bluetooth settings and always need an app to communicate

Comment: @Paulw11 when I use the LightBlue, I can see the machine in the list. But when I scan the devices in ReactNative using this library, https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx, it does not appear in the list even though it is supposed to list down the BLE devices. Any idea why?

Comment: No idea. Do you want to do a cross platform version or just iOS?  If you just want to do ios it might be a good opportunity to learn swift. With cross platform frameworks like react you are having to deal with the abstraction and other peoples code. You can find sample code for swift to discover and connect to BLE peripherals and just run it

Comment: Actually, I am building the app for both platforms. Now, I can detect the machine. It is sometimes missing from the list. Sometimes, it is there. No idea why. Thanks for the help. Got it sorted. Now, I just need to figure out how to send and receive data to and from the WaterRower machine.

Comment: @WaiYanHein try writing and reading with LightBlue or a similar app first until you figure out what the BLE device expects :)

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Thanks.